# rsstail Not Printing Output

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, rss-aggregator

I've installed rsstail 1.8 on my linux box and everything seems to be going smoothly, knock on wood, except for the part where rsstail isn't printing the streams. Running the command, I see that it's retrieving the feed, but nothing ever happens and I'm flummoxed as to why.

```
rsstail -i 300 -t -d -v -u http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/algemeen.rss -n 20
Monitoring RSS feeds:
        http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/algemeen.rss
Check interval: 300
Retrieving RSS feed 'http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/algemeen.rss'...
```

Edit: I'm looking for this to do two things. Given a RSS feed, I'd like to go pull the last N entries for display and second track the feed and update with new articles. Despite pointing at feeds (I've tried CNN and others) it never displays the previous listings, even though browser eyeballing says stuff is there.

Comment: The command you listed works here, maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: I'm quite confused at this point. Script runs, all the dependencies seem to be installed correctly (libmrss, libnxml, libcurl), but it's not displaying.